# In Objective-C, what's difference between import in header file and implementation file?

Tags: objective-c, import, header-files

I'm fresh to learn Objective-C.
Header file is most like a public interface and Implementation file has private interface.

But I'm confused by choosing where to import another header file.

Comment: It would be best to update your question with examples of what you are asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I'm so confused by choosing where to import.

If, and only if, what you are importing is required by the public interface, e.g. an imported type is used in the *signature* of a public method, then import in the interface file.

If what you are importing is only required *internally* by the implementation then import in the implementation file.

The above is a general principle, not tied or limited to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

#import does not cause cross-compilation In Objective-C, # import is used as an improved version of the #include directive. In addition, # import to determine a file can only be imported once, which makes you in the recursive inclusion will not be a problem @ class generally used in the header file need to declare a class instance of the variable when used M file or the need to use #import @ class is to tell the compiler has such a class, as the definition of the class Why do not know @ class generally used in the first document to declare the need to declare an instance of the variable when used in the M file or need to use #import "" means that they create the file, with the first in the current directory to find, if not find to other locations to find, "and" is the relative one is their own One of the files created is a system file